# How to email $_SESSION variables

Tags: php, email, session

I'm have a function which shows the user which products he has added to his cart. In this function I simply echo all the $_SESSION data. The problem is that I want to email all the $_SESSION data. I can't store the function in a variable and simple use $message = $function because in the email I get nothing is being displayed. So my question is: what's the easiest way to email $_SESSION data?

I use this code to display all sessions in a php file:

```
 function cart_summary() {
foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if ($value>0) {
        if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {
            $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
            $id2 = mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id);
            $get_colour_size_category = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id2'";
            $result_colour_size_category = mysql_query($get_colour_size_category);

            while ($get_colour_size_category_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_colour_size_category)) {
                $get_webshop_category = $get_colour_size_category_row['webshop_category'];
                $get_webshop_category2 = mysql_real_escape_string((int)$get_webshop_category);
                $get_name_and_price = "SELECT * FROM webshop_categories WHERE id='$get_webshop_category2'";
                $result_name_and_price = mysql_query($get_name_and_price);
                $row_name_and_price = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_name_and_price);
                $sub = $row_name_and_price['price'] *$value; 
                echo '<tr><td>'. $row_name_and_price['ev_name'] .'&nbsp;'. $get_colour_size_category_row['colour'].'&nbsp;'. $get_colour_size_category_row['size'].'</td><td class="value">&nbsp;'. $value .'&nbsp; </td><td> &euro;'.number_format($row_name_and_price['price'], 2).'</td><td> &euro;'.number_format($sub, 2).'</td><td></td></tr>';


            }
            ?><?

        }
        $total += $sub;
    }

}
```

I want to email the output of this

Comment: you can implode it such as `implode(', ', $_SESSION)` simply

Comment: How does the code where you echo look like?

Comment: Author and future-readers: Please note that the code in the question has a few gaping [SQL-injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) security-holes in it.

Comment: @berkes You're right, I updated the post above and used mysql_real_escape_string and (int) to prevent SQL-injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to put the $_SESSION data in an email by doing the following:

```
function cart_summary() {
$message = "";
 foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
if ($value>0) {
    if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {
        $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
        $id2 = mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id);
        $get_colour_size_category = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$id2'";
        $result_colour_size_category = mysql_query($get_colour_size_category);

        while ($get_colour_size_category_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_colour_size_category)) {
            $get_webshop_category = $get_colour_size_category_row['webshop_category'];
            $get_webshop_category2 = mysql_real_escape_string((int)$get_webshop_category);
            $get_name_and_price = "SELECT * FROM webshop_categories WHERE id='$get_webshop_category2'";
            $result_name_and_price = mysql_query($get_name_and_price);
            $row_name_and_price = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_name_and_price);
            $sub = $row_name_and_price['price'] *$value; 
            $message .= '<tr><td>'. $row_name_and_price['ev_name'] .'&nbsp;'. $get_colour_size_category_row['colour'].'&nbsp;'. $get_colour_size_category_row['size'].'</td><td class="value">&nbsp;'. $value .'&nbsp; </td><td> &euro;'.number_format($row_name_and_price['price'], 2).'</td><td> &euro;'.number_format($sub, 2).'</td><td></td></tr>';


        }
        ?><?

    }
    $total += $sub;
}
  return $message
 }
```

After I did this I was able to email the output of the function with

```
  $message .= cart_email() . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to store the output of your `$_SESSION` array using [`print_r()`](http://php.net/print_r) (by using the optional parameter to return the information, rather than print it):

```
$session_data = print_r($_SESSION, TRUE);
```

Now it is a string containing all the session data and you can use it however you wish.

Comment: That does the trick indeed! The only problem I have now is that I 'attach' each set session to information from the database, and when I use that line of code it doesn't email that information. I have edited my post and added the code I use to display all the sessions on a php file. I simply want to put that in an email but can't get it right...